# What to do when one failed a course in their early years in Bsc which is not part of their major subject

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, physics, grades, attendance

I am a 1st year Bachelor of science student from India, from a well reputed institution, and I want to take physics as my major. I am very passionate about it, and a few of the senior professors continually discuss physics with me and let's say I have a good rapport with them.

The system in my school is that one studies for 2 years, all 4 subjects- Math, Physics, Chemistry and Biology. After that in one's 3rd year, they get to choose their majors, after which their masters will get combined with their bs to give a combined degree including an ms thesis.

My situation is, I have failed this semester's biology course (math and physics are all A+ for the last two semesters, and hopefully maintained like this), and the reason is that I simply didn't maintain proper attendance numbers. This will be a **backlog** for me and I can only clear this backlog in my 4th semester, where I will be graded for this course only on that semester (so in this semester in one's report card, it counts as an F, till the 4th semester, and in the final report card, it will show in two places, one as an F this sem, and once in the 4th sem).

My question is, will this have an affect on my future graduate (PhD) applications to either abroad places or places within India, like TIFR or Harish-Chandra institute, and how much leeway do I have in terms of explaining away this black mark on my card? I have, or at any rate should have by the end of my 5th year here, a bunch of professors who will vouch for me, but I have heard from many sources that most places, especially abroad use grades as a first screening device and this black mark I feel will have a significant negative effect. It would be nice if someone could also explain the process and how one could resolve this and make it not as bad as it is.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-are-ph-d-applications-evaluated-in-the-us-particularly-for-weak-or-borderl

Comment: There are huge differences between different countries and even different universities within the same country regarding how PhD applications are evaluated. In many places this may not harm you at all, but nobody can guarantee that this is so everywhere. Also often it's competitive, so it may depend on how many of your competitors look flawless without such issues.

Comment: I'd say every serious academic is aware that one might has a bad day at some point or that there are still unfair/sexist/"God gets an A, I get a B so perfect students get a C"/whatever professors. I'd say serious professors will most likely not hold this against you if it is not important and.you have other great credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give any advice about India but in the US it wouldn't be a problem and there is nothing to do. If you want to study physics, biology is pretty distant with quite different process. Math might be a different matter. Courses that have a close relation to your major will (here) be weighted more heavily than others. Moreover, very early stumbles are not necessarily limiting. No one is perfect and most of us realize that.

But for better advice, speak with one of your physics instructors who knows the systems and the requirements that will apply to you. If you get the same sort of advice, then rest easy on this issue.